# parameter passing c -> c++ -> c#

Tags: c#, c++, c, parameter-passing

I want to use an extern c function in a c# application through a c++ wrapper.
My code is wrong, and I don't know where is the problem.

The extern c function:

```
extern "C" {
int __cdecl get_minutiae(minutiae **, int **, int **, int **,
                 int **, int **, int *, int *,
                 unsigned char **, int *, int *, int *,
                 unsigned char *, const int, const int,
                 const int, const double, const lfsparms *);
```

The c++ function:

```
void DetectMinutiae::GetMaps(Bitmap ^in_image, int in_pixels_per_inch,
int* quality_map,int map_height,int map_width){
...
get_minutiae(&minutiae_out, &quality_map, &direction_map,
    &low_contrast_map, &low_flow_map, &high_curve_map,
    &map_width, &map_height, &bdata, &bw, &bh, &bd,
    image_data, image->Width, image->Height, image_depth, ippmm, &actual_lfsparms);}
```

From this function I only need the quality_map, map_height, map_width parameters.

The c# side:

```
IntPtr qualityMap_pointer;
int mapp_Height;
int map_Width;

DetectMinutiae.GetMaps(FingerPrint, 500, qualityMap_pointer, mapp_Height,map_Width);
```

**Questions:**

1. Can I forward the c++ function parameters directly to the c
   function parameters, like in the code above?
2. How should I call the c++ function from the c# code?

Comment: `Bitmap^ in_image` looks like he's already using either C++/CLI or C++/CX

Comment: That's not C++, consider removing the tag.